# JSF2: commandLink without javascript

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, lightbox

Is it possible to get the behaviour of a `h:commandLink` without using javascript? I'm using JSF2

If I want to use a **lightbox** component, I will need to have the full generated URL beforehand. If my URLs are action-based, I can only use `h:commandLink`, which generates javascript binded to the mouse click action.

I would like to have the JSF navigation features (eg: use `action="#{bean.action}"` to generate links) and have a way to get the full generated URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<h:outputLink>` or `<h:link>` instead. This generates a plain HTML `<a>` element without the need for a `<h:form>`. To invoke actions, you have to move the logic from the bean action method to the constructor or `@PostConstruct` of the managed bean which is associated with the opened view.

If you need to pass parameters, use `<f:param>` to append them as a query string. You can use `<managed-property>` in `faces-config.xml` (or `@ManagedProperty` when you're already on JSF 2.0) to set those parameters in the bean. You can access them in `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: But with `outputLink` I cannot use the `action` attribute, right? This way I wouldn't be using JSF navigation.

Comment: Did you read beyond the 1st sentence of my answer? Anyway, you can also use `<h:link>` which can take and convert a navigation case outcome value directly.

Comment: Yes, I've read. What I mean in my comment is that I wouldn't be using the outcome stuff. Besides, I cannot use @Postconstruct (unfortunately) because the managed beans are used in different contexts. But thanks for the tip +1

Answer (score 0):

In your action you can use

```
try {
    FacesUtils.redirect("yourUrl.jsf");
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.get().error(e);
}
```

To redirect requests.

Of course you can generate your url as you wish

Hope this helps

Comment: @BalusC in that case you are right and <f:param> is the solution